# Clearing Maps defaults doesn't work

Tags: default-applications

Google Maps was set as the default maps app on my Samsung S8.

I went into settings-->apps-->Maps-->Clear Defaults, and now it says "None set as default".

However, in Calendar when I click on an address - it will launches Maps and doesn't ask me to choose a default. I also have Waze installed ... so why aren't I asked to choose a default again?

Comment: See if clearing cache of calendar helps. Or Try to set up default with this app 
 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.betteropenwith

Comment: Maybe something to do with "Open links by defaut" e.g mapy.google.com etc, play around with these settings and see if it solves the issue